# Adding 32-bit binary in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, binary, ip, decimal

I have to calculate the [IPv4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4) subnet address which can be achieved by adding the IP address binary to the subnet mask binary. I can convert them both to binary with this code

```
    Public Function Dec2Bin(ByVal DeciValue As Long, Optional ByVal NoOfBits As Integer = 8) _
 As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Do While DeciValue > (2 ^ NoOfBits) - 1
        NoOfBits = NoOfBits + 8
    Loop
    Dec2Bin = vbNullString
    For i = 0 To (NoOfBits - 1)
        Dec2Bin = CStr((DeciValue And 2 ^ i) / 2 ^ i) & Dec2Bin
    Next i
End Function
```

But now how do I add the two 32-bit strings together in order to get the subnet adress? I also have the dec-to-bin function, so I don't need any help with that.

Comment: You really don't need a loop for that.

Answer (score 0):

So, I suspect `DeciValue` is your IP address in 32-bit numeric representation and `NoOfBits` is the number of bits in the subnet mask (as 8 for 255.0.0.0, 16 for 255.255.0.0 and 24 for 255.255.255.0 etc).

What you can do is this:

```
Public Function Network_Address(IP as UInteger, Optional Mask as UInteger = 0)
    If Mask = 0 Then
        Mask = 8 * ((IP >> 30) + 1)
    End If
    Network_Address = IP And (4294967295 Xor ((2 ^ (32 - Mask)) - 1))
End Function
```

Now you have the network address as its numeric representation. I suspect thats what you want.

This function will also detect the IP subnet mask size automatically if none is specified.

Comment: Also, you don't have to pass primitive types as `ByVal` if you don't intent to change them in the caller.